# passing a list into a procedure in tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, proc

I want to pass a list into a procedure but not sure how to. I've looked at some examples of how to do this but the examples are too complicated and I don't understand them. The list and procedure are shown below.

```
set RS_CheckBoxes [list kl15_cb din1_cb din2_cb din3_cb din4_cb \
                dinnc_cb ain1_cb ain2_cb ain3_cb ain4_cb a_cb \
                b_cb u_cb v_cb w_cb sin_cb cos_cb th1_cb th2_cb hvil_cb]

tk::button .rs.enter -height 2 -text "Enter" -width 10 -command {x $RS_CheckBoxes}

proc x {$RS_CheckBoxes} {

if {$RS_CheckBoxes} {
puts "ON"
} else {
puts "OFF"
}
}
```

At present I'm using the below code but want to reduce the amount of lines.

```
tk::button .relSel.b -height 2 -text "Enter" -width 10 -command {if {$kl15_cb} {
 puts "$kl15_cb"
 } else {
 puts "$kl15_cb"
 }

 if {$dinnc_cb} {
 puts "$dinnc_cb"
 } else {
 puts "$dinnc_cb"
 }

 if {$din1_cb} {
 puts "$din1_cb"
 } else {
 puts "$din1_cb"
 }

 if {......... etc}
 ............. etc
```

Comment: You will have to explain what you are trying to do. In the second example, you are testing a value and then printing it out regardless of whether it was true or false. In the first example, you use the string `$RS_CheckBoxes` as a parameter name, which is unlikely to be useful. As a first step, change the parameter list to `{RS_CheckBoxes}` but please also make your intents more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not entirely clear. Do you want to pass a list of global variable names into a proc and then print ON or OFF based on their boolean value?

Currently you just seem to be printing the value of the variables in a very complicated way.

```
if {$dinnc_cb} {
    puts "$dinnc_cb"
} else {
    puts "$dinnc_cb"
}
```

is equal to `puts $dinnc_cb` unless you want the code to throw an error when the value cannot be interpreted as a boolean.

If my understanding is correct, try this:

```
proc x {varlist} {
    foreach varname $varlist {
        upvar #0 $varname var
        puts "$varname: [lindex {ON OFF} [expr {!$var}]]"
    }
}
```

The upvar creates a link from the global variable in $varname to the local variable var. You can then use that to check the global variable.

To include a check that the variable is actually set:

```
proc x {varlist} {
    foreach varname $varlist {
        upvar #0 $varname var
        if {[info exists var]} {
            puts "$varname: [lindex {OFF ON} [string is true -strict $var]]"
        } else {
            puts "$varname: INDETERMINATE"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another suggestion: Consider making your checkbox variables array elements. That could make things much easier.

Comment: yeah ok thanks Schelte. Can you show me what the procedure looks like with my values please? Not sure if varlist or varname should be replaced with RS_CheckBoxes.

Comment: The proc can be used as is with your list.

Comment: Hi Schelte, I used what you put and I'm getting "Can't read var, no such variable"

Comment: Then one of the variable names you passed in is not set. As you didn't check for that in your code, I didn't include it in my code. You can add an `info exists var` check, if you need that.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a check for existence of the vars.

Comment: Hi Schelte, I tried the code to check the existence of the vars but I get an error "can't use non-numeric string as operand of "!"" Is there an easier way to do this please?

Comment: @KennyBarber If you are getting this error, there is no way your current code is working properly right now. What do you get if you put `puts $kl15_cb`?

Comment: I have adapted my answer to cope with non-boolean values. Those are considered to be 'OFF'.